# How to Load or Copy Selected Column Data from one Sheet to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am stuck in one of the requirement. I have one Master Sheet (SHeet1) with Headers having 50 Columns and I have another sheet2 with 30 columns with different Header. So now I have to map both Sheet Headers means which Header of Sheet 1 will go to which Header of Sheet 2 and Load/Copy 30 Columns to another Sheet2. Few Column Header of Shee2 will have default Value also which doesn't need mapping.
Below is my requirements.

Master Sheet1--> Total Records 100k+.

```
Object ID   system  project object_id   Revision    Iteration   ows_BaseName    object_name ows_DocumentState   ows_Modified_x0020_By   ows_Created_x0020_By    ows_DocumentOwner   ows_Keywords    ows_Languages   ows_Title   ows_Author  ows_FileDirRef  ows_BaseName
1   System1 Project 1   Object1 Revision1   Iteration1  ows_BaseName1   object_name1    ows_DocumentState1  ModifiedBy1 CreatedBy1  ows_DocumentOwner1  ows_Keywords1   English ows_Title1  ows_Author1 ows_FileDirRef1 ows_BaseName1
2   System2 Project 2   Object2 Revision2   Iteration2  ows_BaseName2   object_name2    ows_DocumentState2  ModifiedBy2 CreatedBy2  ows_DocumentOwner2  ows_Keywords2   English ows_Title2  ows_Author2 ows_FileDirRef2 ows_BaseName2
3   System3 Project 3   Object3 Revision3   Iteration3  ows_BaseName3   object_name3    ows_DocumentState3  ModifiedBy3 CreatedBy3  ows_DocumentOwner3  ows_Keywords3   English ows_Title3  ows_Author3 ows_FileDirRef3 ows_BaseName3
4   System4 Project 4   Object4 Revision4   Iteration4  ows_BaseName4   object_name4    ows_DocumentState4  ModifiedBy4 CreatedBy4  ows_DocumentOwner4  ows_Keywords4   English ows_Title4  ows_Author4 ows_FileDirRef4 ows_BaseName4
```

SHeet 2 --> In this need to be copied -->

```
MASTEROBJECTNUMBER  MASTERORGANIZATION_NAME MASTERCONTAINERTYPE MASTERCONTAINER MASTERCONTAINER_ORG_NAME    MASTERWBMSOURCEIDENTIFIER   REVISION    DEPARTMENT  DESCRIPTION DOCTYPE TITLE   FOLDERPATH  FORMAT  ITERATION   ITERATIONNOTE   CREATEDBY   MODIFIEDBY  LIFECYCLE   LIFECYCLESTATE  CREATEDDATE MODIFIEDDATE    TEAM    TYPE    SOURCEDESCRIPTION   WBMSOURCEIDENTIFIER
1   ABCD    LIBRARY System1 ABCD    10  Revision1   ENG ows_Title1  $$Document  ows_Title1  /Default/Design_Build_Test  Microsoft Excel Iteration1      CreatedBy1  ModifiedBy1 Document LC EFFECTIVE   14-10-2014  14-10-2015      Document    Excel Data  100
2   ABCD    LIBRARY System2 ABCD    20  Revision2   ENG ows_Title2  $$Document  ows_Title2  /Default/Design_Build_Test  Microsoft Excel Iteration2      CreatedBy2  ModifiedBy2 Document LC EFFECTIVE   14-10-2014  14-10-2015      Document    Excel Data  101
3   ABCD    LIBRARY System3 ABCD    30  Revision3   ENG ows_Title3  $$Document  ows_Title3  /Default/Design_Build_Test  Microsoft Excel Iteration3      CreatedBy3  ModifiedBy3 Document LC EFFECTIVE   14-10-2014  14-10-2015      Document    Excel Data  102
```

Comment: SO is not a "Code for me","Teach me to code", or "Find me code" site. It is a site dedicated to help those with existing code that has problems overcome specific problems. If you have code that does not work please post it in the original post using the edit and explain what it is doing that is in error

Comment: Hi Scott.. Thanks a lot for your reply and comment. I had tried with vlookup function but it was not that much efficient. SO thought of doing through VBA but again let me try. Once again Thanks for your response and suggestion.

Comment: In addition to @ScottCraner comment, it is very unclear what is the desired result. Do you have 2 sheets that need to be combined to a 3'ed one? or you want to update sheet 2 with values from sheet 1? what is your key for finding the relevant records in either of the sheets?

Comment: Hi, THanks for the reply. The KEY in Sheet1 is Object ID and in Sheet2 is MASTEROBJECTNUMBER to populate the data.

Below is the Mapping for Sheet2 Column from Sheet1 Column. I have to read Sheet1 and populate the respective data to Sheet2.
I am trying to make it flexible with respect to Column Header, if required I can add more Column or remove few Column Header in mapping and populate the data accordingly.
Sheet2.MASTEROBJECTNUMBER = Sheet1.ObjectID
Sheet2.MASTERORGANIZATION_NAME = "ABCD"
Sheet2.MASTERCONTAINERTYPE = "LIBRARY"
Sheet2.MASTERCONTAINER = Sheet1.system

Comment: Sheet2.MASTERCONTAINER_ORG_NAME = "ABCD"
Sheet2.MASTERWBMSOURCEIDENTIFIER = Sheet1.ObjectID
Sheet2.REVISION = Sheet1.Revision
Sheet2.DEPARTMENT = "ENG"
Sheet2.DESCRIPTION = Sheet1.ows_Title
Sheet2.DOCTYPE = "$$Document"
Sheet2.TITLE = Sheet1.ows_Title
Sheet2.FOLDERPATH = "/Default/Design_Build_Test"
Sheet2.FORMAT = "Microsoft Excel"
Sheet2.ITERATION = Sheet1.Iteration
Sheet2.ITERATIONNOTE = "Notes"
Sheet2.CREATEDBY = Sheet1.ows_Created_x0020_By
Sheet2.MODIFIEDBY = Sheet1.ows_Modified_x0020_By
Sheet2.LIFECYCLE = "Document LC"
Sheet2.LIFECYCLESTATE = Sheet1.ows_DocumentState

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
Public Type ColHeaderDest
    Object As Long
    ID As Long
    system As Long
    project As Long
    object_id  As Long
    REVISION  As Long
    ITERATION As Long
    ows_BaseName  As Long
    object_name As Long
    ows_DocumentState   As Long
    ows_Modified_x0020_By   As Long
    ows_Created_x0020_By    As Long
    ows_DocumentOwner   As Long
    ows_Keywords   As Long
    ows_Languages   As Long
    ows_Title   As Long
    ows_Author  As Long
    ows_FileDirRef  As Long
    ows_BaseName As Long
End Type

Public Type ColHeaderSource
    MASTEROBJECTNUMBER As Long
    MASTERORGANIZATION_NAME As Long
    MASTERCONTAINERTYPE As Long
    MASTERCONTAINER As Long
    MASTERCONTAINER_ORG_NAME As Long
    MASTERWBMSOURCEIDENTIFIER As Long
    REVISION As Long
    DEPARTMENT As Long
    DESCRIPTION As Long
    DOCTYPE As Long
    TITLE As Long
    FOLDERPATH As Long
    FORMAT As Long
    ITERATION As Long
    ITERATIONNOTE As Long
    CREATEDBY As Long
    MODIFIEDBY As Long
    LIFECYCLE As Long
    LIFECYCLESTATE As Long
    CREATEDDATE As Long
    MODIFIEDDATE As Long
    TEAM As Long
    TYPE As Long
    SOURCEDESCRIPTION As Long
    WBMSOURCEIDENTIFIER As Long
End Type

Sub test()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long

    Dim HeaderRowDest As Long
    Dim HeaderRowSource As Long
    ' Where is the column description row ?  This can be automated but I can't be bothered, sorry
    HeaderRowDest = 0
    HeaderRowSource = 0

    Dim shtSource As Worksheet
    Dim shtDestination As Worksheet
    Set shtSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set shtDestination = Worksheets("SHeet 2")

    ' Find last row and next row for source and destination sheets
    Dim LastRowSource As Long
    Dim NextRowDest As Long
    NextRowDest = shtDestination.Range("A" & shtDestination.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    LastRowSource = shtSource.Range("A" & shtSource.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Dim myColHeaderDest As ColHeaderDest
    Dim myColHeaderSource As ColHeaderSource
    ' Get column header for destination sheet
    For x = 1 To shtDestination.Cells(HeaderRowDest, shtDestination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Select Case shtDestination.Cells(HeaderRowDest, x).Range.Text
            Case "Object"
                myColHeaderDest.Object = x
            Case "ID"
                myColHeaderDest.ID = x
            Case "system"
                myColHeaderDest.system = x
            ' ... and so on
        End Select
    Next x

    ' Get column header for source sheet
    For x = 1 To shtSource.Cells(HeaderRowSource, shtSource.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Select Case shtSource.Cells(HeaderRowSource, x).Range.Text
            Case "MASTEROBJECTNUMBER"
                myColHeaderSource.MASTEROBJECTNUMBER = x
            Case "MASTERORGANIZATION_NAME"
                myColHeaderSource.MASTERORGANIZATION_NAME = x
            Case "MASTERCONTAINERTYPE"
                myColHeaderSource.MASTERCONTAINERTYPE = x
            ' ... and so on
        End Select
    Next x

    ' Loop through all rows in the source sheet, starting at the column description row
    For x = HeaderRowSource + 1 To LastRowSource

        NextRowDest = shtDestination.Range("A" & shtDestination.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        For y = 1 To shtSource.Cells(HeaderRowSource, shtSource.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Select Case y
                Case myColHeaderSource.MASTEROBJECTNUMBER
                    shtDestination.Cells(myColHeaderDest.Object, NextRowDest).Text = shtSource.Cells(myColHeaderSource.MASTEROBJECTNUMBER, x)
                Case myColHeaderSource.MASTERORGANIZATION_NAME
                    shtDestination.Cells(myColHeaderDest.ID, NextRowDest).Text = shtSource.Cells(myColHeaderSource.MASTERORGANIZATION_NAME, x)
                Case myColHeaderSource.MASTERCONTAINERTYPE
                    shtDestination.Cells(myColHeaderDest.system, NextRowDest).Text = shtSource.Cells(myColHeaderSource.MASTERCONTAINERTYPE, x)

                ' And so on
            end select
        Next y

    Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: This code won't work as is, obviously, and there was an error about an ambiguous name starting at ows_BaseName , I think there are non-space blank characters in there. You'll have to fix that.

Comment: Thanks  @Shodan. I just changes as owsBaseName by removing _. But its giving compilation error as "Next without For". seems some looping error. Looking into this.

Comment: Yes, there was that missing end select.  You'll need to set HeaderRowDest = 0
    HeaderRowSource = 0 to appropriate values. Probably other things, this is just to get you started.

Comment: Yes.. I updated with that. just exploring now on the compilation error - Run-time Error '1004': Application-defined or Object-defined error.Thanks @Shodan.

Comment: Error at this line in above code.. any help...-- Run-time Error '1004': Application-defined or Object-defined error
For x = 1 To shtDestination.Cells(HeaderRowDest, shtDestination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Comment: Did you update the line Set shtSource = Worksheets("Sheet1") to reflect the name of your worksheets ?

Comment: Yes @Shodan
Set shtSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set shtDestination = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Comment: try commenting it all and add debug.print shtDestination.Cells(HeaderRowDest, shtDestination.Columns.Count).End, see if that works.   then try print shtDestination.Columns.Count or print HeaderRowDest   see if all those have the values they should have